# Trouble with Flex 4 imports

Tags: flash, apache-flex, import, adobe, package

My flex sdk 4.0 is having a hard time finding these classes:

```
import mx.automation.delegates.controls.AlertAutomationImpl;
import mx.automation.delegates.controls.AlertFormAutomationImpl;
```

Any idea why? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you deliberately import those classes?

They are from "automation.swc"

Comment: Thanks! This saves me from hours of headaches.